# Properties don't change when values are assigned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-1.9

I'm a bit of Ruby, noob, and there's some basic thing I'm not getting.  I have something like this:

```
def my_method
    attr1 = 'new 1 value'
    attr2 = 'new 2 value'
    puts "#{attr1} - #{attr2}"
    puts "Should be same? #{to_s}"
end

def to_s
    "#{attr1} - #{attr2}"
end
```

When I call my_method I get:

```
new 1 value - new 2 value 
Should be same? old 1 value - old 2 value
```

Huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in Ruby

```
x = y
```

is *always* an assignment of the value resulting from `y` to the *variable* `x` while

```
obj.x = y
```

is *always* sending the `x=` *message* to the object `obj` (with the value resulting from `y`).

In Ruby *attributes/properties* are really just methods! Thus, try:

```
self.attr1 = 'new 1 value'
self.attr2 = 'new 2 value'
```

On the other hand, `y` *may or may not be* a method call (read: *property* fetch). It depends on if there is already a variable `y` in scope or not because variables *shadow* methods. This is why `attr1` and `attr2` work in `to_s` without needing to be prefixed.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

It's the scope `attr1` and `attr2` are local variables.

So when you're calling `to_s` it looking for `attr_1` and `attr_2` that you've declared  (probably) in the class scope. Those won't get overwritten when you run `my_method` instead you just created a new variable in a smaller scope.

Try using `@attr_1` and `@attr_2` instead.

Check out [Local Variable Gotchas](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators#Local_scope_gotchas)

Comment: Based on the tags I think they're AR attributes, otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: That's true, his question wording does make it sound like a basic Ruby question, But I did have a problem like this when I first started working with Rails and `virtual_attributes`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it. One is to use class-scoped variables instead of local variables:

```
class MyClass

    def my_method
        @attr1 = 'new 1 value'
        @attr2 = 'new 2 value'
        puts "#{@attr1} - #{@attr2}"
        puts "Should be same? #{self.to_s}"
    end

    def to_s
        "#{@attr1} - #{@attr2}"
    end
end

m = MyClass.new
m.my_method
```

Output:

```
new 1 value - new 2 value
Should be same? new 1 value - new 2 value
```

The other way is to use attributes, which you have to specifically call as methods on `self`:

```
class MyClass
    attr_accessor :attr1,:attr2

    def my_method
        self.attr1 = 'new 1 value'
        self.attr2 = 'new 2 value'
        puts "#{attr1} - #{attr2}"
        puts "Should be same? #{self.to_s}"
    end

    def to_s
        "#{attr1} - #{attr2}"
    end
end

m = MyClass.new
m.my_method
```

This has the same output.

Comment: Based on the tags, I think they're likely AR attributes.

Comment: In that case, the 2nd solution fits the bill, except that he would not need to declare the accessors.